# How to use WriteMultipleProperty using bacpypes

Tags: service, bacnet, bac0, bacpypes

I tried using BAC0 writemultiple part to access the writemultiple to my server but it didnt worked well,So can anyone suggest to implement the writemultipleproperty to the server using bacpypes..

Suggestion reagrding to implement the writemultiple property